# How to get a cookie by a part of its name using php?

Tags: php, cookies

Lets say I have multiple cookies like so:

```
add_listing_123=1
add_listing_456=1
add_listing_789=1
```

How can I retrieve all cookies starting with "add_listing_" ?

And when retrieved how would I go about parsing out the numbers from the cookies using php, so that my end result is an array of 123, 456, 789?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$listings = array ();
foreach ($_COOKIE as $name => $content) {
    if (strpos($name, 'add_listing_') === 0 && $content == 1) {
        $listings[] = substr($name, strlen('add_listing_'));
    }
}

var_dump($listings);
```

This iterates through all the cookies to find those that start with `add_listing_` (if the position of `add_listing_` in the name is `0`). If so, it adds to the `$listings` array the part after `add_listing_`.

Comment: Thanks M Miller - when doing a print_r(intval($content)); I am getting "1" ... am I missing a step?

Comment: This assumes that you only want to add the listing if the value of it is `1` (e.g. you wouldn't want the listing if the cookie had it set to `0`).